# Without duplicating child elements, how to show/hide parent DIV based on device width?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have 2 DIV blocks. One is shown for XS devices and other is shown for all other devices.

```html
<!--For small, medium, large and X-Large devices-->
    <div *ngIf="art.isSelected == false" class="unselected-artefacts" fxLayout="row" fxShow fxHide.xs="true">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/" alt="user image" fxFlex="20">
      <div fxFlex="70" class="artefacts-metadata">
        <p class="artefact-title">{{art.title}}</p>
        <p>{{art.modifiedOn}}</p>
      </div>
      <img fxFlex="10 "src="./assets/plus-icon.png" alt="select" class="cursor-pointer">
    </div>

    <!--For X-small devices-->
    <div fxLayout="row" class="unselected-artefacts" fxHide fxShow.xs="hide" [style.background]="(art.isSelected == true) ? '#a3b9dd' : 'none'">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/" alt="user image" fxFlex="20">
      <div fxFlex="70" class="artefacts-metadata">
        <p class="artefact-title">{{art.title}}</p>
        <p>{{art.modifiedOn}}</p>
      </div>
      <img fxFlex="10" [src]="(art.isSelected == true) ? './assets/minus-icon.png' : './assets/plus-icon.png'" alt="select" class="cursor-pointer">
    </div>
```

Now for both blocks, the children remain almost same (except for img.class="cursor-pointer") while the parent's (div.class="unselected-artefacts") properties change based on device orientation.

How to remove duplicate code in this case and optimize it better?

Comment: If it's only about a class, [take a look at this](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API) : it says you can use ngClass to give classes according to breakpoints like `ngClass.xs="myClass"`

Comment: It is not just a class. I have *ngIf which is only for parent block in larger devices. Similarly, conditional styling `[style.background]="(art.isSelected == true) ? '#a3b9dd' : 'none'"` for parent block in XS devices. How could I make them class dependent?

Comment: You mean device-width dependant, right ? You could use [Angular flex layouts](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) which is amazing for giving styles or classes to components based on the device.

Comment: Yea I have used flex layout to hide/show based on device widths. I just was thinking about a way to remove duplication of child elements in two places just because the parents have different properties.

Comment: Use the flex layout on only one element, where you put all your conditions, simple as that